# what does this C++ line of code mean "sol<?=f((1<<n)-1,i,0)+abs(P[i])*price;"

Tags: c++, c, operators

Could anyone help me to understand following line of code:

```
sol< ?=f((1<< n)-1,i,0)+abs(P[i])*price;
```

I am studying an algorithm written using c++ and it has following operator `< ?=` . My problem is with understanding `< ?=` operator. Also when I compile this code using g++ compiler , it gives error message for above line of code line of code

following is the error message returned.

> Hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> Hello.cpp:115: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
>
> Hello.cpp:142: error: expected primary-expression before ‘?’ token
>
> Hello.cpp:142: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
>
> Hello.cpp:142: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘;’ token
>
> Hello.cpp:142: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token

Maybe `< ?=` it is not a single operator, but I can not understand what exactly this line of code does.

Thanks in advance for the time you spent reading this post.

Comment: What's the context around this line? Are you sure it is actually C or C++?

Comment: Hi Frank
Here is the Full Code http://pastebin.com/aSZCSeTZ. i got this line of code from an Algorithm submitted for Google Code jam 2008. This algorithm has gained first place in that competition.

Comment: If this code is from the Google Code jam 2008, can you give a pointer to the original in the list of finals: http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard?c=32011#vf=1

Comment: http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard?c=32003#vf=1
compititor sclo : problem D : Question 80pt

Comment: It means its author does not know (or purposedly ignores) the value of "readable code".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a GNU extension. It's basically a "lower than" operator.

```
int a = 3;
a <?= 2;
cout << a << endl; // prints 2, because 2 < 3

a <?= 10;
cout << a << endl; // prints 2 as well, because 10 > 2
```

Read more [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html).

Comment: Thanks budy , you are a Hero :)

Comment: You know, every time I think I've seen every last bit of evil from GCC, I'm pinged between the eyes with something even more evil.  +1 for you.  -100,000 for the GCC team.  Ugh!

Comment: I compiled above code using g++ compiler, do you have some idea about why above error is returned.

Comment: @Kltis: The `<?` and `>?` have been deprecated in favor of the clearer `std::min` and `std::max`.

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm not really familiar with the operator myself since I never used it :). The code compiled for me on the GNU compiler however. What version are you using?

Comment: @IVIad: i am using version 4.4.1 ubuntu version.

Comment: Oh, well, I'm using 3.4.5 on Windows. Maybe they removed it. Just replace it with a min function.

Comment: It's been deprecated since G++ 4.0, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear for anyone reading this and not being able to follow; `<?=` and `>?=` are assignment versions of `<?` and `>?` which are deprecated GCC extensions which served the purpose of `(x>y)?x:y` or `(x<y)?x:y` respectively.

Therefore, `x <?= y;` would be `x = x <? y;` which is `x = (x<y) ? x : y;`

Most compiler vendors introduce language extensions, and many make it into future language standards.  Usually these extensions are either just very easy to add or make the job of writing standard libraries much easier.

Answer (score 1):

It could almost be a line of PHP code though: all it needs is remove a space to form  at the end.

```
<?= foo(); ?>
```

is equivalent to

```
<?php echo foo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the C grammar [here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html)

The only use of `?` is in the ternary operator:

```
conditional_expression
    : logical_or_expression
    | logical_or_expression '?' expression ':' conditional_expression
    ;
```

Where the `?` is followed by an expression. This does not happen in your case. So your code is ***not a valid*** C.

Answer (score -1):

This line isn't a line of code. That's why it doesn't compile. It is meaningless to ask what it does.

Comment: i want to know about the "< ? =" operator, I am not expecting explanation on the full line bcoz i have not included the rest of the code.

Comment: There is no `< ?=` operator; it isn't two operators either. To reiterate, this isn't code. It just resembles code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aSZCSeTZ , here is the link to full code I am referring. This code has given the first place in Google Code jam 2008. that is why i am interested to know how it works actually